# Get value from html side controls and pass it to server side controls

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a question about server side and html side controls.

This is my code

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                                   "Enter Id", 
                                   " prompt('Enter your Id  ....');", 
                                   true);
```

I want to get value that user entered?

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<form id="theform" runat="server">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidValue" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Script for get value from hidden field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function storeinput(id) {
            document.getElementById("<%=hidValue.ClientID%>").value = id;
        }
</script>

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "prompt", "var id = prompt('Enter your Id .'); storeinput(id);", true);
```

Comment: Thanks alot,but where is the value that user enterd?

Comment: Change type="hidden" to type="text"

Comment: storeinput function has your value

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

Please define hidden variable in ASPX page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidValue" runat="server" />
```

Please write below code at CodeBehind:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "prompt", "document.getElementById('" + hidValue.ClientID + "').value = prompt('Enter your Id .'); alert(document.getElementById('" + hidValue.ClientID + "').value); ", true);
```